# How to get my ajax to work in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

My code works in Firefox, but it does not work on the IE
Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  function saseangol() {
    request.open ("GET", "saseangol.html",true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if(request.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = request.responseText;
      }

    }
    request.send(null);
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  function sase() {
    request.open ("GET", "sase.html",true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if(request.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = request.responseText;
      }

    }
    request.send(null);
  }
</script>
```

Can someone help me plz?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific than "does not work?"  Do you get an error or anything?

Comment: I suspect it's because he's using `XMLHTTPRequest()` which isn't the same ajax object that all browsers use.  For this reason, I'd suggest jQuery.

Comment: @nzifnab I believe XMLHTTPRequest works for IE7 and above. OP, are you dealing with IE6?

Comment: Hmm, you may be right.  It's been some time since I tried using ajax without just going with jQuery.  Native functions make my head explode.  But there are other browser quirks that jQuery would isolate the developer from that he might be running into.  I'm not familiar enough with non-jquery ajax'ing to formulate an answer to the question though.

Comment: @nzifnab I absolutely agree. I haven't done native AJAX without jQuery in years. So much nicer to get those event handlers to do the work for you.

Comment: Regardless of my familiarity with `XHR`, it's a little odd that he's defining the `request` variable twice in the global scope, between function definitions. That seems redundant since the functions will not run between those definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check which version of IE you are using, and does it support XMLHttpRequest. Because IE7+ has built-in XMLHttpRequest object.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Old versions of Internet Explorer (IE5 and IE6) use an ActiveX Object:

```
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

in javascript:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AJAX cross-browser you can do something like this...

```
function createXHR() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0"];

        for (var i = 0, length = versions.length; i < length; i++) {
            try {
                var xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                return xhr;
            } catch (error) {}
        }
    }

    alert("Your Browser Doesn't Support XmlHttp");

    return null;
}
```

You use asynchronous request so when it should be performed, you just redeclared `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();` *variable* and so there might be reason of your problem